# ModuleNotFoundError when running code, but works in ipython

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitvector

I'm trying to use the BitVector library in python 3.6. When I run ipython and run "from BitVector import BitVector", I get no error and can successfully use BitVector. However, when I try to run my actual code that contains "from BitVector import BitVector", I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "testharness.py", line 1, in <module>
      from BitVector import BitVector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BitVector'
```

I installed BitVector using "pip3 install BitVector"

Comment: Did you install the BitVector package in your python3 environment?

Comment: @mistiru how do i make sure i did?

Comment: simply try : pip3 install BitVector, and try again

Comment: @mistiru I get: Requirement already satisfied: BitVector in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Comment: How do you "run [your] actual code that contains "from BitVector import BitVector""?

Comment: @mistiru even when I comment everything else out in my code besides the line : from BitVector import BitVector, I still get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183435/discussion-between-mistiru-and-user1045890).